# Error in installation of Openstack in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, openstack, openstack-horizon

I have been installing Openstack in my Virtualbox ubuntu and after I executed ./stack.sh after some time the installation got exit with this error
"ebtables v1.8.4 (nf_tables): table `broute' is incompatible, use 'nft' tool."

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do  : Installing an OpenStack is quite Huge project  I mean do you follow official documentations ?

Answer (score 6):

I know it could be a bit late, but still:

> Encountered this on Ubuntu 20.04 as well, workaround was to change to iptable->legacy and attempt stacking again.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install iptables
apt-get install arptables
apt-get install ebtables

update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy || true
update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy || true
update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy || true
update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-legacy || true
```

more on this:

1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/devstack/+bug/1885198
2. https://wiki.debian.org/it/iptables

Comment: apt-get install iptables 
you need to install iptables not iptable